# Closed form for Poisson stochastic process with mean dependent on the state space

Tags: poisson-distribution, random-variable

Suppose that $Y$ is a stochastic process, such that $\Pr(Y_n = y) \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$ is modelled as a Poisson random variable with rate $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a function of the previous state $Y_{n-1}$. What conditions must be imposed on this function before we are able to derive a closed form for the probability distribution function of $Y_t$ for any $t >0$ when given the state $Y_0$?

For example, in a population of animals, the number of offspring in a year is modelled as a Poisson random variable with mean proportional to the population. Ignoring deaths, this mean will increase as the population increases each year.